# Load arbitrary resources during page loading & show loading indicator

Tags: javascript, html

I'm loading some resources using AJAX at page load. What I would like to achieve is keep the "loading" status of the page (i.e. `document.readyState == "interactive"`) until these resources are loaded, so that the browser still shows the loading indicator. Is this possible?